# Webcam not working

Tags: arch-linux, usb, camera

My USB Webcam was working about a week ago, before I updated from 5.13 to 5.16. After the update my USB Webcam is no longer working. I don't know what I did.

Comment: That's very little information to work on. Could you add to your question the part of output of `lsusb` that concerns your camera? It will be something like `Bus 011 Device 702: ID 0520:e697 EYE Webcam 4K 1110` Did you try more than one application? If you boot the older kernel, does the problem still show?

Comment: Did you update Linux kernel? Can you reboot to a previous version of the kernel?

Comment: I didn't do anything sense asking question and it now works

Comment: "sense" = "since"? Maybe consider to delete your question then